# Is there an easy way to group an EF ResultSet into a new object?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, group-by

I have an EF Stored Procedure (Function Import) that returns a result set, and I want that result set grouped on multiple levels. Is there an easy way to group the results into a new object?

My result set contains objects with the following data:

```
CategoryId
EventId
EventInstanceId
Name
DueDate
```

I would like to group the results by Categories and Events, so I end up with `Category.List<Event>.List<EventInstances>`

```
class Category
{
    List<Event> Events;
}

class Event
{
    List<EventInstance> Instances;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was going to just delete my question since I figured it out, but since there's an up-vote I'll post the solution I found

```
List<CategoryModel> list =
    (from category in context.GetEvents(date, date) // Stored Procedure
        group category by category.CategoryId 
        into groupedByCategory // Group by Category
        select new CategoryModel
        {
            CategoryId = groupedByCategory.Key,
            Events = new ObservableCollection<EventModel>
            (
                from evt in groupedByCategory
                group evt by new { evt.EventId, evt.AssignedUserId, evt.EventName, evt.EventDescription, evt.IsRecurring } 
                into groupedByEvent // Sub-Group for Events
                select new EventModel
                {
                    EventId = groupedByCategory.Key,
                    AssignedUserId = groupedByEvent.Key.AssignedUserId,
                    EventDescription = groupedByEvent.Key.EventDescription,
                    EventName = groupedByEvent.Key.EventName,
                    IsRecurring = groupedByEvent.Key.IsRecurring,
                    Instances = new ObservableCollection<EventInstanceModel>
                        (
                            from item in groupedByEvent
                                select new EventInstanceModel
                                {
                                    CompletedDate = item.CompletedDate,
                                    CompletedUserId = item.CompletedUserId,
                                    DueDate = item.DueDate,
                                    EventInstanceId = item.EventInstanceId,
                                    IsSkipped = item.IsSkipped.GetValueOrDefault()
                                }
                        )
                }
            )
        }
    ).ToList();
```